# C# Windows service not working as intended

Tags: c#, windows-services

I wrote a windows service that is supposed to check a table and if that table has rows then it creates a report and drops it in a folder. It writes the timestamp for stopping and starting but the OnElapsedTime is not working. The first block of code is the service and the second is the method I wrote to send reports (I know this works as I tested it before I made it a service). Not sure why it won't generate the report.

```
partial class Service2 : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(); // name space(using System.Timers;) 
    public Service2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 600000; //number in milisecinds  
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
    }
    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForReports();
        WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
    }
    public void WriteToFile(string Message)
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.   
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
    }
    public void CheckForReports()
    {
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection;

            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=****;Database=ChrisCMS; Trusted_Connection=True;");
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (sqlConnection)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    "Select * from SentReports;");

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    DataClasses1DataContext classes1DataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                    foreach (SentReport entity in classes1DataContext.SentReports)
                    {
                        new ReportSender.MyReportRenderer().RenderTest(entity.QueueReports);
                        classes1DataContext.SentReports.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);

                    }
                    classes1DataContext.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE SentReports");
                    classes1DataContext.SubmitChanges();
                }
                reader.Close();

            }


        }
    }
}


public class MyReportRenderer
{
    private rs2005.ReportingService2010 rs;
    private rs2005Execution.ReportExecutionService rsExec;



    public void RenderTest(String matchedCaseNumber)
    {
        string HistoryID = (string)null;

        string DeviceInfo = (string)null;
        string MimeType = string.Empty;
        string Encoding = string.Empty;
        string Extension = string.Empty;
        ReportSender.rs2005Execution.Warning[] Warnings = (ReportSender.rs2005Execution.Warning[])null;
        string[] StreamIds = (string[])null;
        this.rs = new ReportingService2010();
        this.rsExec = new ReportExecutionService();
        this.rs.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        this.rsExec.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        this.rs.Url = "http://***/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx";
        this.rsExec.Url = "http://***/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx";


        try
        {
            // Load the selected report.
            this.rsExec.LoadReport("/ChrisPhiladelphiaReports/AFSReport", HistoryID);
            //string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
            // Set the parameters for the report needed.

            rs2005Execution.ParameterValue[] parameters = new rs2005Execution.ParameterValue[1];
            parameters[0] = new rs2005Execution.ParameterValue();
            parameters[0].Name = "paramCaseNum";
            parameters[0].Value = matchedCaseNumber;

            rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

            // get pdf of report 
            byte[] buffer = this.rsExec.Render("PDF", DeviceInfo, out Extension, out MimeType, out Encoding, out Warnings, out StreamIds);
            DataClasses1DataContext classes1DataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<CaseInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<CaseInfo>((IQueryable<CaseInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<CaseInfo>(), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, string>>)(c => c.ParcelNumber)));
            //string str1 = Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<CaseInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<CaseInfo>((IQueryable<CaseInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<CaseInfo>(), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, string>>)(c => c.Summary)));
            // string str2 = Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<CaseInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<CaseInfo>((IQueryable<CaseInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<CaseInfo>(), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, string>>)(c => string.Format("{0:C}", (object)c.Total))));
            string str3 = Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<CaseInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<CaseInfo>((IQueryable<CaseInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<CaseInfo>(), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, string>>)(c => c.Premises)));
            //MailMessage message = new MailMessage("Reports@aalacquest.com", "gcg@aalacquest.com", "Report for Property " + Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<CaseInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<CaseInfo>((IQueryable<CaseInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<CaseInfo>(), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<CaseInfo, string>>)(c => c.Premises))), "MuniReport.");
            //MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("george.greiner@aalacquest.com");
            //((Collection<MailAddress>)message.CC).Add(mailAddress);
            //SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("localhost");
            //message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment((Stream)new MemoryStream(buffer), string.Format("{0}" + str3 + ".pdf", (object)"BRT")));
            //smtpClient.Send(message);
            FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("D:\\ClientWebFiles\\Reports\\" + str3 + ".pdf");
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the service crash? Does ‘CheckForReports’ maybe throw an exception? (You have some unnecessary {} there) also I don’t think you can show a MessageBox from a service this way....

Comment: I agree with the above. I think you need some more exception handling. Perhaps logging the exception if possible would be useful too. The way it is set up right now, if the call to ssrs failed, the write to file failed or the call to the database failed then your service would just crash.

Comment: @MarcoRebsamen the service does not crash.  It does absolutely nothing that I can see.  I will put some error handling in but I know everything besides the windowsservice part works as intended.

Comment: When you start the service, does it actually start running, i.e., can you see it as a running process in Task Manager?  If not, then `OnStart()` is failing perhaps due to a permissions problem in `WriteToFile()`.  Of course, you can always debug the service and see where the problem is occurring.  Call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in `Main()`, and then set your breakpoints accordingly.

Comment: @MattDavis Yes it starts running.  When it gets to OnElapsedTime it does not execute the method nor does it write a line.  If I have it write the line first it will do so and then do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake.  It was a dumb one too.  Method never actually checked for the report as I missed a line which is bolded below:

```
public void CheckForReports()
{
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection;

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=****;Database=ChrisCMS; Trusted_Connection=True;");
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (sqlConnection)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "Select * from SentReports;");
            ***command.Connection = sqlConnection;***
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                DataClasses1DataContext classes1DataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                foreach (SentReport entity in classes1DataContext.SentReports)
                {
                    new ReportSender.MyReportRenderer().RenderTest(entity.QueueReports);
                    classes1DataContext.SentReports.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);

                }
                classes1DataContext.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE SentReports");
                classes1DataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
            reader.Close();

        }


    }
}
```